# SharedPreferences Not working in Firebase Messaging Background Handler in Release APK

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

The issue I'm encountering is with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) notifications. I've configured the notifications to include a custom sound based on the application's language. The notifications work correctly, and the sound plays according to the app language in the debug mode APK.
However, in the release mode APK, the notification play defaults sound from the device's ringtone instead of playing according to the application language.

In the background handler, I've utilized SharedPreferences to retrieve the application's language. Despite this, the notification sound does not adhere to the application language and instead defaults to the device's ringtone in the release APK.

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
          await Firebase.initializeApp();
          print('on background msg ${message.toMap().toString()}');
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          await prefs.reload();
          String sound =await prefs.getString("soundname")??'english';
          print("sound name is on background---$sound");
          LocalNotificationService.createNotificationChannel(
              "id",
              "title",
              "body",
              sound,
              message);
        }

        
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
    
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
     LocalNotificationService.initialize();
    
      FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
        print('Message = getInitialMessage');
      });
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
    
    }
    static void createNotificationChannel(String id, String name,
          String description, String sound, RemoteMessage message) async {
        print("sound in notification is---$sound");
        final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
        var androidNotificationChannel;
        final idd = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
        final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              idd.toString(),
              "Driver",
              channelDescription: "this is our channel",
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.high,
              playSound: true,
              sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound),
              icon: "@drawable/logo",
            ));
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          DateTime.now().millisecond,
          message.notification!.title == null ? "" : message.notification!.title,
          message.notification!.body,
          notificationDetails,
        );
```